How do I get a callback for QListWidgetItem becoming visible in PyQT5
I created a simple MediaBrowser using a QListWidget in PyQT5:
class MediaBrowser(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, database: Database, viewtab, dir_path):
        QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.log = logging.getLogger('mediahug')
        self.database = database
        self.viewtab = viewtab

        self.setLayoutMode(QListView.Batched)
        self.setBatchSize(10000)
        self.setUniformItemSizes(True)

        self.current_directory = dir_path
        # self.current_file_widgets = []
        self.thumb_loader_thread = None
        self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.selection_change)

        # Should theoretically speed things up but it does not
        # self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QListWidget.AdjustToContents)

        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.setResizeMode(QListWidget.Adjust)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT))
        self.load_files(dir_path)

...
...

    def all_files(self):
        return self.findItems('*', Qt.MatchWildcard)

    def load_files(self, dir_path):
        if self.thumb_loader_thread and self.thumb_loader_thread.isRunning():
            self.log.info('Killing Previous Thumbnail Loading Thread')
            self.thumb_loader_thread.requestInterruption()
            self.thumb_loader_thread.wait(sys.maxsize)
            self.log.info('Previous Thumbnail Thread Done')

        self.clear()
        # Load New File widgets
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path, f))]
        for f in onlyfiles:
            vid = join(dir_path, f)
            self.log.debug(f"Creating File/Thumb Widget {vid}")
            self.addItem(ThumbWidget(vid, self.database))

        self.thumb_loader_thread = ThumbLoaderThread(self.all_files(), dir_path)
        self.thumb_loader_thread.start()

The MediaBrowser which is a QListWidget, adds a bunch of ThumbWidget items (which are QListWidgetItem objects) when it starts:
class ThumbWidget(QListWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, filename: str, database):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self)
        self.filename = filename
        self.database = database
        self.setText(basename(self.filename))
        standard_file_icon = QWidget().style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileIcon)
        self.setIcon(standard_file_icon)
        self.setSizeHint(QSize(THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT + FILENAME_MARGIN))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Thumbnail for {self.filename}'

    def load_thumb(self):
        metadata = self.database.file_metadata(self.filename)
        img_thumb = metadata['thumb']
        if img_thumb:
            img = QPixmap()
            img.loadFromData(img_thumb, 'JPEG')
            self.setIcon(QIcon(img))

This takes a lot of time at startup. I'd like to only load a thumbnail for the item when it is scrolled into view. Elsewhere within my code, the MediaBrowser is within a QScrollArea.
        self.media_scroller = QScrollArea()
        self.media_scroller.setWidget(self._media_browser)
        self.media_scroller.setWidgetResizable(True)

Is there any way to get events to know when a particular QWidgetItem is current scrolled in/out of view? That way I can load and unload thumbnails, making for more efficient startup times.
The full code for this project can be found here:
https://gitlab.com/djsumdog/mediahug/-/tree/master/mediahug/gui/viewtab

The standard approach is described in this example by Qt: Implement your own model and build the items as required in fetchMore(). I don't think it supports unloading items, though

Item-based solutions like QListWidget are always going to be a sub-optimal choice since they incur the large cost of creating an instance of the item-class for every index. This is in addition to the further issue of loading large data-sets (which affects all solutions). A QListView with a custom model that implements fetch-more will be the most efficient solution - although it may have some drawbacks (such as scrolling performance).

There are many reasons for which you could get slow start up time: 1. as noted by ekhumoro, QListWidget is not ideal for large amount of entries, especially if you're using subclasses for them; 2. the loading of all icons, which is slowed down by I/O access and image decompression; 3. non explicit size hints, which forces the view to retrieve the hints of each item in order to set their final geometries. Finally, the loading of the data that is eventually used to create items can be a relevant aspect. Large data sets that also rely on images are normally implemented with two optimizations: »


implement a lazy loading (using fetchMore as noted above); 2. only load images on demand (typically, when shown), which can be achieved by using both timers and a custom delegate that will only load the image when it's being painted (the first time paint() is called the delegate will check if the image has not been loaded yet, then it reads and sets it explicitly for the related index. Note that your attempt in using setSizeAdjustPolicy does not speed up things, in fact it results in the opposite. Also, setting an item view within a QScrollArea is completely pointless.


Thanks for all the comments on the question. It's interesting the linked documentation was to the Python section of QT's website, but the code on it was C++. I've used it to create a model for handling files in PyQT5. There are some things like database and a thumbnailer I implement elsewhere, but it should be easy to adapt for anyone looking for a Python implementation of a QAbstractListModel that handles files:
import logging
from functools import lru_cache
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, basename

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QVariant, Qt, QSize, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyle, QWidget



class FileListModel(QAbstractListModel):

    numberPopulated = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, database: Database, dir_path: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.log = logging.getLogger('<your app name>')
        self.database = database
        self.files = []
        self.loaded_file_count = 0
        self.set_dir_path(dir_path)

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = QtCore.QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return 0 if parent.isValid() else self.loaded_file_count

    def set_dir_path(self, dir_path: str):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.files = []
        self.loaded_file_count = 0
        only_files = [f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path, f))]
        for f in only_files:
            vid = join(dir_path, f)
            self.files.append(vid)
        self.endResetModel()

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()

        if index.row() >= len(self.files) or index.row() < 0:
            return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            filename = basename(self.files[index.row()])
            return QVariant(filename)

        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            thumb = self.__load_thumb(self.files[index.row()])
            if thumb:
                return thumb
            else:
                return QWidget().style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileIcon)

        if role == Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return QSize(THUMB_WIDTH, THUMB_HEIGHT + FILENAME_MARGIN)

        return QVariant()

    def fetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> None:
        if parent.isValid():
            return

        remainder = len(self.files) - self.loaded_file_count
        items_to_fetch = min(100, remainder)
        if items_to_fetch <= 0:
            self.log.debug("No More Items to Fetch")
            return

        self.log.debug(f'Loaded Items: {self.loaded_file_count} / Items to Fetch: {items_to_fetch}')

        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.loaded_file_count, self.loaded_file_count + items_to_fetch - 1)
        self.loaded_file_count += items_to_fetch
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.numberPopulated.emit(items_to_fetch)

    def canFetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        if parent.isValid():
            return False
        can_fetch = self.loaded_file_count < len(self.files)
        self.log.debug(f'Can Fetch More? {can_fetch}')
        return can_fetch

    @lru_cache(maxsize=5000)
    def __load_thumb(self, filename):
        self.log.debug(f'Loading Thumbnail For {filename}')
        metadata = self.database.file_metadata(filename)
        img_thumb = metadata['thumb']
        if img_thumb:
            img = QPixmap()
            img.loadFromData(img_thumb, 'JPEG')
            return QIcon(img)

In the above example, I'm loading thumbnails from my database layer and added an lru_cache annotation around it. This works for now, but there will be a delay on large folders while scrolling, if thumbnails haven't been generated/cached yet.
A future improvement and speed up would involve changing the if role == Qt.DecorationRole section of data() to always return a loading icon if the thumbnail is not immediately available in memory. Then have a background tasks, thread or delegate that then loads or generates the thumbnail in the background, and use the dataChanged() call on the model to indicate the thumbnail is now ready.
I also changed the QListWidget to a QListView and change the following in the constructor:
        self.setLayoutMode(QListView.Batched)
        self.setBatchSize(10)
        self.setUniformItemSizes(True)

        self.file_list_model = FileListModel(database, dir_path)
        self.setModel(self.file_list_model)
        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selection_change)


About the linked example: 99% of the time, you should generally avoid the "Qt for Python" documentation and their codes (including examples, as in this case). The PySide docs are automatically generated based on the original C++ API, with few and rare exceptions that have been manually checked and/or modified; the code, if in Python, is also often automatically "translated" (so, unreliable). The reference documentation is always the C++ API one, then eventually check the Python docs (or use help() in the Python interactive shell) only if in doubt about argument/return signatures.
